# Append width or height at element.style, depending on array value, plain JS

Tags: javascript

I am trying to add `width` or `height` dynamically to element.style in my javascript, because that way I can vary on the way my color overlay is fading out (left to right or bottom to top).
The way I am doing it atm is

```
let posArray = ['width', 'height']
let randInt = Math.round(Math.random())
```

if I do `console.log(posArray[randInt])` this returns me a correct string of width or height because the randInt generates a number between 0 and 1.

However when I try to do `element.style.posArray[randInt] = '0';` I am only getting errors.

Is there a way to solve this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your syntax is trying to access a `posArray` property on element.style. You should do something like this instead:

```
const propertyName = posArray[randInt];
element.style[propertyName ] = '0';
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, that solved the syntax error indeed!

Problem now is that, the function is toggled at any scroll evt, so the toggle between width and height is way to fast, resulting in the color overlay always disappearing in the top left corner, hmmm ...